# PHP Убирать параметры из URL, если содержащие цифры

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, url

Ссылки на товары на сайте имеют вид такой

```
test.ru/catalog/holodilniki/3574/
```

Если мы добавляем к последнему уровню (где цифры - id товара) какой-то параметр (при том это может быть что угодно и начинаться как угодно:

```
test.ru/catalog/holodilniki/3574_blabla/
test.ru/catalog/holodilniki/3574&chtoto/
test.ru/catalog/holodilniki/3574?lalala/
```

То все равно остаемся на странице товара. Если задача поставить на страницы товаров атрибут `rel="canonical"`, а для этого надо знать непосредственно верную ссылку - без параметра.

Вопрос: можно ли как-то "очистить" определенную часть строки, в моем случае /3574/ от всех параметров - от всего, что не цифры?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понял Вашу задачу, то можно использовать это выражение:

```
'/\d+\K\pP[^\/]+\/$/m'
```

https://regex101.com/r/rlCIzz/2

На примере возьмем строки, и преобразуем их. На выходе получим нужный результат.

```
$string = '
    test.ru/catalog/holodilniki/3574_blabl232a/
    test.ru/catalog/holodilniki/3574&chto2323to/
    test.ru/catalog/holodilniki/3574?lalala/
';

echo preg_replace('/\d+\K\pP[^\/]+\/$/m', '/', $string);
// test.ru/catalog/holodilniki/3574/
```

https://3v4l.org/kFha9

Comment: к сожалению, не работает если урл такойй, например:     test.ru/catalog/holodilniki/3574blablabla/

Comment: @KBriezy, пробуйте https://regex101.com/r/rlCIzz/3

Comment: спасибо вам большое за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Можно формировать ссылку на текущий товар и использовать ее в качестве canonical.